# How to get the api_key to use the google analytics APIs?

Tags: python, google-analytics

I am currently working on a task to call to Google Analytics API asynchronously. Currently, we are calling the Google Analytics report method that gets the data in batches as written below.

```py
`analytics.reports().batchGet`
```

Please find the ref: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet

I am looking for an async way to call this, I found [aiogoogle](https://aiogoogle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but didn't find a way to call the batchGet.

How can I achieve this with an asynchronous functionality?

Comment: the documentation which you pointed reference said "This API is deprecated and does not support Google Analytics 4 (GA4) properties. Use the Data API to access the reporting features for GA4 properties." it means no more support this API.